# Multivariable analysis - convergent subsequence of $ x_n=(\sin(n) ,\cos(n), 1+(-1)^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus

If $ x_n=(\sin(n) ,\cos(n), 1+(-1)^n),$ does the sequence $\{x_n\} \in \mathbb R^3$ have a convergent subsequence?

For this problem I'm not sure if a convergent subsequence would exist for this specific sequence since $ 1 + (-1)^n $ isn't bounded and thus doesn't converge which should force $ x_n $ to not have a convergent subsequence? Am I correct or if not what would be the proper subsequence for $x_n$?

Comment: It *is* bounded, so by the $3$-dimensional version of Bolzano-Weierstrass, it does have a convergent subsequence. Indeed the limit points are $S^1\times\{0,2\}$.

Comment: You are mistaken in saying the sequence $\{ 1 + (-1)^n \}_{n=1}^\infty$ is not bounded. It is bounded, since it alternates between $0$ and $2.$ But you are right in saying it does not converge. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sequence does have a convergent subsequence.

First let's show that $\{(\sin n, \cos n)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ has a convergent subsequence.

After that, since $1+(-1)^n$ alternates between $0$ and $2$ we can just keep all the even-numbered terms (or all of the odd-numbered terms) of the sequence referred to in the paragraph above.

If $2\pi$ were exactly $44/7,$ then whenever $n$ is a multiple of $44,$ thus when $n=44k,$ then $n=7k(2\pi)$ and so $(\cos n,\sin n) = (1,0).$ But $2\pi$ is irrational, so we consider a sequence of rational numbers with increasing denominators approaching $2\pi.$ For example, $710/113 \approx 2\pi,$ so when $n=710,$ then $(\sin n,\cos n) \approx (\sin(113(2\pi)), \cos(113(2\pi)) = (1,0). $ In this way, we get a subsequence approaching $(1,0).$

Comment: It's clear that for a given positive integer $q$, we can find a positive integer $p$ satisfying $\displaystyle \left|\frac{p}{q} - 2\pi \right| \leq \frac{1}{2q}$, but this only gives us $\displaystyle |p - 2\pi q| \leq \frac{1}{2}$. Is it obvious that we can sharpen the approximation so that the error between $p$ and some multiple of $2\pi$ will converge to zero?

Comment: @Bungo : Good point. If $2\pi$ were exactly $44/7,$ then the sequence $(\cos n, \sin n)$ would start repeating after $44$ terms, and otherwise, the only way the sequence can fail to have a subsequence approaching $(1,0)$ is if there is some arc of the unit circle containing $(1,0)$ into which the sequence never falls. That means we need a sequence of rationals that approaches $2\pi$ fairly fast. That can be found as a subsequence within any sequence of rationals that approaches $2\pi. \qquad$